# Can't select first value in json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I can't seem to select the first value inside the json object.
I've tried `array[0][0]`, but it returns `undefined`.

```
[ { 'Room 1': 11017,
'Room 2': 2651,
'Room 3': 1,
'Room 4': 2,
'Room 5': 1,
'Room 6': 1,
'Room 7': 3,
'Room 8': 5,
'Room 9': 3661,
'Room 10': 2 } ]
```

Comment: Because there is no key as `0` in object..Try `array[0]['Room 1']`

Comment: There *is no "first" value* with any guarantee. The solutions using `Object.keys()` are unsafe if the proper order is a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access keys using a string, not an index:

`array[0]['Room 1']`

Edit:
There is a method to access keys based on order of definition.  However, while almost all implementations of `Object.keys` currently return in the correct order, it is not *required* to do so by the spec:

```
var keys = Object.keys( array[0] );
var fifth = keys[4];
var value = array[0][fifth];
```

Comment: Made an edit showing how that can work.

Comment: You guys really shouldn't post stuff that can fail. Beginners end up using solutions that have the *appearance* of working without heeding the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's an object inside the array. You can access an array's elements by using `array[0]`, but for an object it'd have to be `object.key` or `object["key"]`.

To make this data structure more dynamic, I'd suggest breaking it up like so:

`roomNumbers = [11017, 2651, 1, 2, 1]...(and so on)`

That way, you access a number without knowing the room ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array, containing 1 object, which has keys and not indexes. So reference the first key:

```
array[0]['Room 1']
```

If you need to pull without know the key names, you can get them via `Object.keys(obj)`;

```
var availableKeys = Object.keys(array[0]);
var val = array[0][availableKeys[0]]; //replace availableKeys index with what you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element is an object, it's trying to retrieve property `0` which is `undefined`. So you need to use the property name to get the value (eg : `array[0]['Room 1']`).

---

You can use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get the key array then get the value using that. But there is no guarantee of the order, since **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** returns keys in an arbitrary order.

```js
var array = [{
  'Room 1': 11017,
  'Room 2': 2651,
  'Room 3': 1,
  'Room 4': 2,
  'Room 5': 1,
  'Room 6': 1,
  'Room 7': 3,
  'Room 8': 5,
  'Room 9': 3661,
  'Room 10': 2
}]

console.log(
  array[0][Object.keys(array[0])[0]]
);
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to get it in certain order then use a nested array instead.

```js
var array = [[
  11017,
  2651,
  1,
   2,
   1,
   1,
   3,
   5,
   3661,
   2
]]

console.log(
  array[0][0]
);
```

Comment: Keep in mind also– If the items you are trying to access need to be in a specific order, objects do not maintain order. If the order is important, each of the key values should be in their own array index.

Comment: _`Object.keys` returns keys in arbitrary order_

Comment: @Arunesh : glad to help you :)

Comment: @Arunesh: There's no guarantee that `[0]` will represent the `Room 1` key/value pair, so you shouldn't use this solution since it is allowed to produce any ordering it wants without warning.